# Cast object to stdClass

Tags: php

I have a database model with `__get` and `__set` functions that prevent dynamic creation of properties (to prevent typing mistakes):

```
class UserModel
{
    public $Name;
    public $LanguageCode; // f.e. "EN", "NL", ...

    public function __get($name)
    {
        throw new Exception("$name is not a member");
    }
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        throw new Exception("$name is not a member");
    }
}
```

Now, I have an array of `UserModel` instances (`$users`) that I want to pass to a templating engine. Therefore, I want to run `array_map` on the array and add an additional property `LanguageText`, to be used in the template.

```
$users = array_map(function ($v)
{
    $v = (object)$v; // this doesn't help to cast away from UserModel type
    $v->LanguageText = GetLanguageText($v->LanguageCode);
    return $v;
}, $users);
// pass $users to templating engine
```

Of course the line `$v->LanguageText = ...` throws an error because I try to add a dynamic property. I tried this: `$v = (object)$v;` to cast the `UserModel` object to `stdClass`, but the type is unchanged. Any ideas how to cast away from `UserModel` without having to serialize/unserialize the data?

I'm using PHP 5.3.5

Comment: Why not just add the LanguageText property to the class definition?

Comment: Because I have written database code that works like the `.NET Entity framework`. Each property in the model must map to a column in the database table.

Comment: If you don't care about getting the property back into a UserModel object then see my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to do a double cast to do what you want...

```
$v = (object)(array)$v;
```

Comment: Depending on the framework being used this might be a good use case for a view helper so the view can resolve the language text without having to rely on the context to provide it.